# Apache PerlAuthzHandler and form POST vars

Tags: apache, perl, authorization, mod-perl

I have a mod_perl [PerlAuthzHandler](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/handlers/http.html#PerlAuthzHandler) authorizing access to directories served by Apache2. In terms of controlling access it is working well.

A side effect, though, is that it seems to be preventing POST form variables from being available to PHP apps in the protected locations.  At least when I comment out the PerlAuthzHandler and reload Apache the PHP app functions again.  I think either the full environment is not being inherited by Perl or Perl is sending a cleansed environment on.

Is it possible to ensure that all POST variables are available to the PHP application after authorization?

---

### Details

User authentication is managed by simplesamlphp on this box, the SP, and ADFS, the IdP.  The addition to the simplesamlphp installation is the use of PerlAuthzHandler.

#### Apache configuration

The Apache configuration for the location in question looks like this:

```
<Location /activity>

   ErrorDocument 401 "/simplesaml/authmemcookie.php"
   AuthName "MCLAnet"
   AuthType Cookie
   Require valid-user

   PerlSetvar Auth_memCookie_SessionTableSize "40"
   PerlAuthzHandler My::simple
   PerlSetVar VALID_GROUP_EXPR "status-acad or staff-g"

</Location>
```

#### Authorization handler

The authorization handler retrieves group memberships recorded in setting up the session and compared to a `VALID_GROUP_EXPRESSION` in the PerlSetVar:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

package My::simple;

# Version 1.0  MCLA CSS

use Apache2::Access ();
use Apache2::RequestUtil ();

# load modules that are going to be used
use Data::Dumper;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Cookie;
use Cache::Memcached;
use PHP::Serialization qw(serialize unserialize);

# compile (or import) constants
use Apache2::Const -compile => qw(OK FORBIDDEN);

$debug=0;
$debug_file="/tmp/xxx";

dmp('prerun',('test'));

sub handler {

      my $r = shift;

      my $user = $r->user;
      dmp('0 user',$user);

      # ------------------------ get valid group(s) for this session

      my $valid_group_expr=$r->dir_config("VALID_GROUP_EXPR");
      dmp('1 valid group list',$valid_group_expr);

      # -- get the session cooke to retrieve the session <ID>

      $query = new CGI;
      # fetch existing cookies
      my %cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
      # dmp('Cookies',%cookies);

      my $ID = $cookies{'SimpleSAMLSessionID'}->value;
      dmp('2 SimpleSAMLSessionID value',$ID);

      my $SessionID='simpleSAMLphp.session.' . $ID;

      # -- use the session ID to look up the value of memcached key simpleSAMLphp.session.<ID>

      my $cache =  new Cache::Memcached {
         'servers' => ['127.0.0.1:11211'],
         'compress_threshold' => 10_000,
       };

      # Get the value from cache:
      my $value = $cache->get($SessionID);

      # dmp('mamcache value',($value));

      # -- use the value data to find the groups

      my $hashref = unserialize($value);
      # dmp('mamcache unserialized',($hashref));

      my %hash = %{ $hashref };
      %hash = % { $hash {'data'}{chr(0) . 'SimpleSAML_Session' . chr(0) . 'authData'}{'default-sp'}{'Attributes'} };
      my @groups = @ { $hash{'groups'} };

      dmp("3 Comparing $valid_group_expr to", \@groups);
      my $result=evaluate($valid_group_expr,@groups);
      if ($result) {
             dmp("this guy oK",$result);
             return Apache2::Const::HTTP_OK;
      }

     dmp("blowing this guy off",$result);
     $r->log_reason("Not a member of group " . $valid_group_expr);
      return Apache2::Const::FORBIDDEN;

    # return Apache2::Const::HTTP_FORBIDDEN;
    # return Apache2::Const::HTTP_OK;
    # return Apache2::Const::DECLINED;
}

# ======================= utility functions

# evaluate returns the boolean value of the expression $expr
#          after substituting membership information in @groups
#
# valid operators are
#
#    &&, and, AND             logical AND
#    ||, or, OR               logical OR
#    !, NOT, not              logical NOT
#
# expression must be infix and precidence can be indicated by ()

sub evaluate {

   my ($expr,@groups)=@_;
   # print "$expr\n";
   # print Dumper(\%group_hash);

   # operator tokens
   my %token_hash = (
       '(' => '(',
       ')' => ')',
       'AND' => '&&',
       'and' => '&&',
       'or' => '||',
       'OR' => '||',
       '!' => '!',
       'not' => '!',
       'NOT' => '!',
   ) ;

   # add the group array into the token hash as TRUEs
   foreach $v (@groups) {
      $v=~s/ /_/g;
      $token_hash{$v} = 1;
   }
   dmp('merged hash',\%token_hash);

   # merge the two hashes into %token_hash
   # foreach my $tkey ( keys %group_hash) { $token_hash{$tkey} = $group_hash{$tkey}; }
   # print Dumper(\%token_hash);

   $expr=~s/\(/ ( /g;
   $expr=~s/\)/ ) /g;
   $expr=~s/\!/ ! /g;

   # print "$expr\n";
   my @expr_hash=split (/ /,$expr);

   $expr='';
   foreach my $t (@expr_hash) {
       if ($t ne '') {
          if (exists ($token_hash{$t})) { $t = $token_hash{$t} } else {$t = 0;}
          $expr = $expr . "$t ";
       }
   }
   dmp("expression",$expr);
   my $result=0;
   my $assignment="\$result = $expr;";
   dmp("assignment",$assignment);
   eval($assignment);
   dmp("result",$result);
   return $result;

}

# debug dump structure funcion
sub dmp {

   if ($debug == 1) {

     my ($label,@value) = @_;
     my $temp = Dumper(@value);
     open (T, ">>$debug_file"); #   || die "Can't open $debug_file: $!\n";
     print T "$label: $temp\n";
     close (T);

   }

}

1;
```

#### Failing PHP script

The simple PHP form below displays no value when the Perl authorization is enabled.  If I comment out the PerlAuthzHandler line both `$_POST'[submit']` and `$_POST['in1']` are set.

```php
<?php

   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { print_r($_POST); }

   $form=<<<EOT
      <form name="test" action="y.php" method="post">
         <input name="in1">
         <input type="submit" name="submit">
      </form>
EOT;

   print $form;

?>
```

Again, authentication (simplesamlphp/ADFS) and authorization both work as expected.  The exception is that when authorization is used no `$_POST` variables are available.

Comment: Please show your Apache configuration, the contents of your `PerlAuthzHandler`, and a simple, reproducible example of a PHP script that fails.

Comment: Hi pha, I've edited your question to fix the formatting issues you were having, plus a few other minor tweaks. Including a code block in a numbered list is tricky (you need to use an empty HTML comment, e.g. `<!-- -->`, between the list item and the code block, with a blank line before and after the comment); needless to say, this isn't described in the [Markdown help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help), so don't worry about not knowing. If you ever have questions about how to do things on SO, you can search http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ and ask a question if there isn't one already.

Comment: Also, this is a very well-written question. Welcome to Stack Overflow and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLUTION**

As often happens the problem was of my own making.  One of the kind monks at [perlmonks.org](http://permonks.org) pointed out that the Perl handler contained the line:

```
$query = new CGI;
```

Removing that did it. Since I was in fact only accessing but not changing anything there was no point to it and in fact $query was never used.